# Convert this SQL to cakephp find()

Tags: sql, cakephp

How can I write this SQL using cakephp find()

```
SELECT a.user_id FROM answers a
INNER JOIN answers a1 ON a1.question_id=1 AND a1.answer_value='Pooch'
INNER JOIN answers a2 ON a2.question_id=2 AND a2.answer_value='Peach'
GROUP BY a.user_id
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806650/in-cakephp-how-to-retrieve-joined-result-from-multiple-tables

Comment: I need to join the same table with different criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ad hoc joins](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/nate/2009/01/21/quick-tip-doing-ad-hoc-joins-in-model-find) or set up a self-referential model association. The former may be the easiest option because it's just building the SQL you already know and understand. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a good section of the cookbook that shows you how to join tables, that dont automatically happen through your associations (hasOne, hasMany) etc.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1047/Joining-tables

Comment: I've read that but it doesn't help. I need to join the same table multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You can use converter by dogmatic69 here : http://cakephptutor.wordpress.com/2013/02/25/convert-sql-query-to-cakefind/