# Add one more condition in controller with cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have created following function in controller:

```
    function beg($status_id = null) {
    if(!empty($status_id)){
        $conditions = array('winner_id >' => 0, 'Product.beginner' => '1', 'Product.status_id' => $status_id);
    }else{
        $conditions = array('winner_id >' => 0, 'Product.beginner' => '1');
    }
    $this->paginate = array('conditions' => $conditions, 'limit' => $this->appConfigurations['adminPageLimit'], 'order' => array('end_time' => 'asc'), 'contain' => array('Product' => array('Category'), 'Status', 'Winner'));

    $this->set('products', $this->paginate('Product'));
    $this->set('statuses', $this->Product->Status->find('list'));
    $this->set('selected', $status_id);
    $this->set('extraCrumb', array('title' => __('Product List', true), 'url' => 'beg'));

    $this->render('beg');
}
```

I want to add one more condition in it, that is:

Search winner_id from Accounts table match with 'user_id' in accounts table, and only add Products in the list where winner Id is in Accounts table ('user_id' in accounts table).

Anybody know how to add condition with  this `$conditions = array('winner_id >' => 0, 'Product.beginner' => '1', 'Product.status_id' => $status_id);`

I have added on more condition like below

```
 $acc_id = $this->Account->find('all', array('Account.user_id'));
$conditions += array('Product.winner_id' => $acc_id);
```

But its not working, anybody please tell me where I am getting wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you wanted to add one more condition to the `$conditions` than you can try using code

`$conditions += array('Product.status_id' => $status_id);`

hope it will help

Comment: I have account table and want winner_id from Product Table to be in Account table user_id. But when I do $conditions += array('Product.winner_id' => 'Account.user_id'); its not working. Issue with this part is 'Account.user_id', how will I populate it and then use iteration to check if id found then show it

Comment: if i am correct, then a join will be required to accomplish the task. Then in this case above `$condtion += ..` wont required. This functionality can be achieved by `join` clause with _account_ table
with `on` clause.
More info [Click Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806650/how-do-i-write-a-join-query-across-multiple-tables-in-cakephp).


Hope it would make sense to you

Comment: Is this correct, or how will I add these values in condition? $acc_id = 1,2,3,4,5;
$conditions += array('Product.winner_id' => $acc_id);

Comment: `$acc_id` need to be an array to equip with `array('Product.winner_id' => $acc_id);`

in this case the condition will be something like 
`where Product.winner_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)`

Check this and let me know

Comment: I did with either a lengthy way, but it worked atleast..Run a query take values and then did this 'Product.winner_id' => array_map('intval', explode(',', $val))..which worked finally..:)

Comment: This can also be achieved by Cakephp Association relation 

[more info](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html).

You can check with `$conditions = array('Product.winner_id IN('.$acc_id.')` without calling ` explode` method.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can add it with code like below

```
if ($account_user){
      $conditions['accounts.user_id'] = $account_userid;
}
```

above code will add one more conditions in same array $conditions.

Comment: I have to add this condition below or above the code $conditions = array('winner_id >' => 0, 'Product.beginner' => '1', 'Product.status_id' => $status_id);

Comment: yes 

above of 

 $this->paginate = array('conditions' => $conditions, 'limit' => $this->appConfigurations['adminPageLimit'], 'order' => array('end_time' => 'asc'), 'contain' => array('Product' => array('Category'), 'Status', 'Winner'));