# How to get data from different DB in same query, in Cakephp?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have different DB with the same tables each, and I need to group the information from those tables.

For example:

- table orders db 1
- table orders db 2

The idea in pseudo-code would be:

```
"SELECT * FROM orders(db 1), orders(db 2)"
```

Do you know an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use traditional ANSI syntax?

```
"SELECT * FROM db1.orders Orders1, db2.orders Orders2"
```

I've not worked with Cakephp specifically, but if you want to do a cross join (which is horribly nonperformant btw, there are better ways to do it), thats the standard method.

Comment: Yes I guess is something like this, but at the moment I don't get to do it with Cakephp.

Comment: this might help => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806650/how-do-i-write-a-join-query-across-multiple-tables-in-cakephp. also, i HIGHLY doubt u actually want a cross join (which returns the cartesian product of all possible combinations of all rows). you might be thinking of a full outer join.