# Querying across multiple tables in CakePHP 3.x ORM

Tags: php, cakephp

I have three tables *Countries, Cities* and *Addresses*. Their relationship is Countries hasMany Cities, Cities hasMany Addresses. So Its something like this Countries->Cities->Addresses.

If I want to get all addresses in a certain city I can do it like this

```
$this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Cities']
    ];
    $this->set('addresses', $this->paginate($this->Addresses));
```

If I want to get all Cities in a certain Country I can do like that as well.

**What I want is I want to get all Addresses in a Certain Country.**

Note: Addresses ***does not*** contain foreign key for Countries, instead its in the Cities.

Possible query would be: `SELECT a.*, c.* FROM countries a LEFT JOIN cities b ON a.id=b.country_id LEFT JOIN addresses c ON b.id=c.city_id`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I write a join query across multiple tables in CakePHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806650/how-do-i-write-a-join-query-across-multiple-tables-in-cakephp)

Comment: I will edit the question. Since the duplicate is in older version way 2009, now cake has its ORM.

Answer (score 0):

I think you looking for something like this ([from the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#adding-joins)):

```
    <?php

    $query = $countries->find()
        ->hydrate(false)
        ->join([
            'City' => [
                'table' => 'cities',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => 'Country.id = City.country_id'
            ],
            'Address' => [
                'table' => 'addresses',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => 'City.id = Address.city_id'
            ]
        ]);
```

The hydratate method tells the ORM not to try generating entities. If you want the entities to be generated try removing that part.