# Join query retrieving data from only one table cakephp 3

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.4

I am new to cakephp. I am usign query builder to fetch details from two tables using join in cakephp query builder.But the query i am writing is fetching details only from one table. Need help to get data from other table as well.

This is my code to fetch data by joining two tables:

```
public function edit($id = null) {

    $events_table = TableRegistry::get('Events');

    $events = $events_table->find('all') 
            ->hydrate(false)
            ->join([
            'CourseType'=>  [
                        'table'      => 'coursetype',
                        'type'       => 'LEFT',
                        'conditions' => 'Events.type = CourseType.coursetype_id',
                    ]                   
            ])->where(['Events.id' => $id]);

     $event = $events->toArray();       
     $this->set('event', $event);
}
```

As a result i am getting only details from events table. But i need data from coursetype also.Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/845519/4514250. May be it is helpful.

Comment: Is that for cakephp 3.x or cakephp 2.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually adding joins won't cause any additional data to be selected, you'd have to do that on your own by specifying the fields to be selected via the `select()` method.

```
$events = $events_table
    ->find('all') 
    ->hydrate(false)
    ->select($events_table)
    // either add the fields one by one, or pass a table object
    // as above to select all fields of the table
    ->select(['CourseType.id', 'CourseType.xyz', /* ... */])
    // ...
```

I'd suggest to use use containments instead, ie setup the required association if not already present, and then simply use `contain()`:

```
$events = $events_table
    ->find('all') 
    ->hydrate(false)
    ->contain('CourseType')
    ->where(['Events.id' => $id]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Selecting Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-data)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Loading Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#loading-associations)**

Comment: is `CourseType` model name?

Comment: That depends on your setup, I just used the same aliases as you did in your example. If you'd follow the [**naming conventions**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions) of CakePHP, then the "model" (table class) name would be `Coursetype`, and if you'd follow the convetions for database table names too, then that would be `course_types`, and the model  name would be `CourseTypes`. @VaruniNR

Comment: Okay Thank you. Will try it out

Comment: With contain i can use join?

Comment: No, you use `contain()` instead of `join()`. @VaruniNR

Comment: Your answer was useful. I got the answer. Thanks a lot. Though i did not experiment it with contain i got it using the `select()`.

Answer (score -3):

your solution here: [CakePHP find method with JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079908/cakephp-find-method-with-join)

Comment: I think thats for cakephp 2.x. Can you send answer for cakephp 3.x?