# How to do join with 3 tables in CakePHP 2.x

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, join

I am new in cakephp and I would like to do join with cakephp version 2.x. 
I have 3 tables :

users = id, username, pass, groupd_id, role

projects = id, name, start_date, end_date, category

assigns = id, project_id, user_id

I would like to do like this below: (but in cakephp)

```
select projects.name from projects
    left join assigns on assigns.project_id = projects.id
    left join users on users.id = assigns.user_id where assigns.user_id = 24
```

Comment: This question has been asked before. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806650/how-do-i-write-a-join-query-across-multiple-tables-in-cakephp) :)
GL

Comment: Hello All, Thanks. my problem fixed